# Load includes on existing model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to load includes on an existing model in sequelize. In express we pre check the models to see if they exist in the middleware.

So once we're in the actual "controller" we want to run some includes on that existing model that is passed in.

```
req.models.item.incude([
    {model: Post, as: 'posts'}
])
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

I know we can do something like this.

```
return req.models.item.getThing()
    .then(function (thing) {
        req.models.item.thing = thing;

        return req.models.item;
    });
```

But:

1. My expansions for includes are a dynamic property that come via url parameters, so they are not know ahead of time.
2. It I return the above you will not see the "thing" in the response. I need it nicely built as part of the original instance.

Something like a `.with('thing', 'other.thing');` notation would be nice. Or in the case of sequelize `.with({include: ...});` or `.include([{model: ...}]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable `req.models.item` is already an [Instance](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/) but without its other related instances ("includes"), then you could include them using something like the following code:

```
Item.findAll({ 
  where: req.models.item.where(),
  include: [{
    model: SomeAssociateModel,
  }]
})
.then(function(itemWithAssoc) {
  // itemWithAssoc is an Instance for the same DB record as item, but with its associations
});
```

See [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#relations-associations) for some documentation. See [here](https://github.com/cfogelberg/sequelize-playground/tree/master/tests/12-find-with-includes) for a script demo'ing this.

---

**Update: Given the instance, how do I just get the associated models?**

To do this just use the automatically generated "getAssociation" getter functions, e.g.:

```
function find_associations_of_instance(instance) {
  return instance.getDetails();
}
```

I've updated the script to include this as an example. For more information on these functions, see the [SequelizeJS docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/has-many/).

Comment: Doesn't this repeat the query for the item select though. The point is to only pull the includes since I already have the item.

Comment: @Rob - ok gotcha, I've edited my original answer to include how to do this as well

Comment: Hmm, just throws errors that the methods don't exist, both on the instance and the model.

Comment: Using sequelize 3.13.0.

Comment: Hmmm. Script updated to use 3.13.0 and it runs without errors on my machine. What are the errors? What is the stack trace?

Comment: Quick note in case this is what is causing the problem: The method is not always called getDetails - it is only called that because in my demo script the associated model is called 'detail'.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I realized that after the comment. I'm aware of this functionality, however now it's a separate piece of data and not attached to the model directly. I tried attaching it manually but there are too many things sequelize is doing behind the scenes.I tried just a `model.customer = model.getCustomer()` for instance and it's there. But when I spit it out using express `.json()` response it doesn't show up.

Comment: Hmm, can you post a repro of your problem somewhere?